# nginx restart single host without affecting other

Tags: nginx

My nginx.conf has two different server blocks, one pointing to the main site and the other to my api server. Now whenever I deploy something to either one of them,  and stop the server it stops both these servers. Is there a way to stop/restart one particular server without disturbing the other one?

=============
EDIT:

I've been doing it wrong. I should not be restarting nginx. In my case all I wanted was Passenger to recogonize my code changes and refresh. Simply creating a `tmp/restart.txt` file inside the `Rails.root` directory did the trick for me.

For anyone facing the same issue, create an empty file `tmp/restart.txt` in your root path and every time that you want to deploly simply touch it.

```
touch tmp/restart.txt
```

For more details, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480078/how-to-make-nginx-be-aware-of-rails-code-changes

Comment: This is not clear. Why would you want to restart nginx after deploying a new build of your web app?

Comment: My bad. Please see my edit. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no option to restart individual virtual server instances. However, there shouldn't even be any need to do that when app server is upgraded.

Comment: My bad. I've updated my question with the proper way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Use when existing connections must work
`` kill -HUP `cat /path_to/nginx/file.pid`
HUP changing configuration, keeping up with a changed time zone (only for FreeBSD and Linux),
starting new worker processes with a new configuration, graceful shutdown of old worker processes ``

In your case it is not clear why you need to reboot nginx?

Comment: Sorry about the delayed response. You're right. I've been doing it wrong. I just wanted to intimate passenger about the changes in my rails code. placing a tmp/restart.txt file inside the rails root directory did the trick. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

you can use reload instead of restart

```
#nginx -s reload
```

or

```
sudo service nginx reload
```